# TabControl Focus in Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, tabcontrol

I'm using a Popup control with following xaml

```
<Popup AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding PopupContext.IsOpen}"
       x:Name="__popup" StaysOpen="False">
  <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
    <TabItem Header="123"><Button>test</Button></TabItem>
  </TabControl>
</Popup>
```

If I click Button and click outside of the popup, popup is closed normally. But if I click a TabItem and click outside parent window (if I click desktop, popup close normally), it doesn't close popup.

EDIT

I set Popup.IsOpen to true from ContextMenu.Opened event soo UIElement is focused and cant lostfocus. If UIElement.ContextMenu.Closed event fired and MouseLeaved to popup, I set Popup.IsOpen property to false. (soo if not clicked popup, it's close with ContextMenu)

```
private void viewModelMasa_ContextMenuOpening(MasaViewModel Sender, System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs args)
    {
        MasaView source = args.Source as MasaView;
        ContextMenu menu = source.ContextMenu;
        RoutedEventHandler openHandler = null;
        RoutedEventHandler closeHandler = null;

        this.PopupContext.Position = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;

        closeHandler = (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!this.PopupContext.IsFocus)  // Setting from Popup MouseEnter and MouseLeave event;
                {
                    this.PopupContext.IsOpen = false;
                }
                menu.Closed -= closeHandler;
            };

        openHandler = (sender, e) =>
            {
                ContextMenu contextMenu = sender as ContextMenu;
                if (contextMenu != null)
                {

                    this.PopupContext.IsFocus = false;
                    System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point();
                    var pos = contextMenu.TranslatePoint(point,this.PopupContext.Parent);
                    this.PopupContext.Rectangle = new Rect(pos.X, pos.Y, contextMenu.ActualWidth, contextMenu.ActualHeight);
                    this.PopupContext.IsOpen = true;

                }
                menu.Opened -= openHandler;
            };
        menu.Opened += openHandler;
        menu.Closed += closeHandler;
    }
```

Comment: Could you try setting the 'focusable' property of the Tab Control to 'false'? - it MIGHT work (can't test where I'm at right now).

Comment: i set focusable property to false but dont work.

Comment: This code works ok. Whatever the problem, it\`s somewhere else (code behind maybe or where you open the Popup).